# Overlapping objects can't be selected individually

Tags: modeling

I'm just starting out. I'm as green as it gets...and I'm stymied. I'm trying to build a biped with primitives with the intention to use Sculpt Mode to smooth it out. I've got a sphere for the head, another overlaps it for the hair. But the two shapes insist on moving as one. I can't select one and move it without moving the other. How to handle this?

Comment: Hello :). You probably have both meshes inside one object. In *Edit mode* go *Mesh > Separate > By Loose Parts*. That will make them separate objects.